# null reference not evaluating to nothing

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to test if an object is nothing before I get it's value, but I get an error "NullReferenceException"

happens on the first line here：

```
If Not ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet.ItemRef.FullName Is Nothing Then
    li.FullName = ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet.ItemRef.FullName.GetValue()
End If
```

System.NullReferenceException
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

How can I test for this, without just handling the error in a try/catch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are more objects involved that can be nothing:

- `ORInvoiceLineRet` can be nothing
- `ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet` can be nothing
- `ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet.ItemRef` can be nothing
- `ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet.ItemRef.FullName` can be nothing

So the only safe way here is:

```
If ORInvoiceLineRet IsNot Nothing _
   AndAlso ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet IsNot Nothing _
   AndAlso ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet.ItemRef IsNot Nothing _
   AndAlso ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet.ItemRef.FullName IsNot Nothing  Then
    li.FullName = ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet.ItemRef.FullName.GetValue()
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Either `ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet.ItemRef` is `Nothing`, `ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet` is `Nothing` or `ORInvoiceLineRet` is `Nothing`.

Its hard to access the properties of `Nothing` so a `NullReferenceException` is thrown.

You could test the chain all in one go using [`OrElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
If Not (ORInvoiceLineRet Is Nothing OrElse _
    ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet Is Nothing OrElse _
    ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet.ItemRef Is Nothing OrElse _
    ORInvoiceLineRet.InvoiceLineRet.ItemRef.FullName Is Nothing)

End If
```

If the left expression evaluates to `True`, [`OrElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will not evaluate the right.

Comment: But OP wants to set `li.FullName` is none of them are nothing. You are checking the opposite.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes I made a mistake, corrected, and I upvoted your answer